# Where can I find my suggested edits to a post if they were rejected in peer review?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have [edited an answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/31686/104429).

I was curious whether my suggested edits (which I made obviously with best intentions) where accepted or not. I think they were rejected, because I cannot find them in the edit history.

I am generally aware how sugegsted edits work and have read the FAQ, but cannot find in the FAQ **where my (suggested, but rejected) edits are stored now** (for me to review) - if they are still stored at all.

Comment: This is answered in our FAQ [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), under the section "How can I check on my own suggested edits?".

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog I read through teh FAQ, but could find where my (suggested, but rejected) edits are stored now - if they are stored at all.

Comment: As I said (or later edited), it's in the section titled "How can I check on my own suggested edits?". It's in the "All actions" subtab of your user profile.

Comment: Thanks for this, @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog."All actions" tab - makes sense. :-) I think this is worth being put in an answer here. The FAQ does not come up on a search for my question and the section with the information I am looking for is pretty far buried away...

Comment: Yeah, that's a fault of the way FAQs are currently structured, and there isn't much technical room to change them. Your question is still useful as a signpost to allow people who search to find it. Here, per policy, we close questions as duplicates of questions tagged [tag:faq] if the answer to that question also addresses this one, even though the questions themselves may not be exactly the same, to link users to the canonical posts regarding topics. See [this section of our FAQ on how Meta Stack Exchange works](/a/47635) and the last section of [our FAQ on duplicate closures](/a/10844).

Comment: Thanks for that acknowledgment @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog. I am pretty frustrated by StackExchange's  Duplicate Question procedure - So often it feels like I have to *fight* for questions which IMHO look not like duplicates - at least in a narrow sense of a google-style discovery searches...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to all actions on the activity tab of your profile. Then, click suggestions in the second tab of your profile. The URL is:

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/{ID}/{username}?tab=activity&sort=suggestions`

[image: screenshot showing where to click the tabs]

Comment: You can specify the URL using `current` for the user name, this works by replacing the word "current" automagically: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions